# Can I use mt RPi as some form of Parental Control to block YouTube to _some_ LAN devices?

Tags: networking

I'm trying to block Youtube on my various children's devices, but have it allowed/open on the parents devices.

Initially I was thinking of OpenDNS but that would block *everything* in this LAN. I *could* manually change the DNS settings of the 'parents' devices, but this too is a pain.

I was really hoping that I could use my RPI (which is doing nothing/not turned on/gathering dust) to be some middleware hardware device that could be used to intercept any traffics from a specific set of MAC's or static LAN IP's and .. if going to YouTube, deny.

Also (which makes this really hard) is that I don't want to block YouTube 24x7 .. but 'on demand'. So for example, I wake up ... kids have commitments (home schooling, chores, etc), I wish to 'flick a switch' and YouTube is now blocked. They finish their home schooling / chores, I can now flick it back on.

Is there anything out there for the RPi that I could leverage?

Edit: Please keep any 'parenting opinions' out of this question. Lets keep this civil and on target.

Comment: Have you looked into configuring this on your gateway/cable modem/router?? RPi can certainly do this, but I imagine you'd prefer something easy.

Comment: Yes - i'm using a Ubuquiti AMPLIFI ... and it's really dumbed down.

Answer (score 3):

You can try [KeexyBox](https://keexybox.org) - an open source gateway software for Raspberry Pi. It does parental control with website filtering, time access and can force bing, google and youtube safe search.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use a proxy server. I haven't used one for years so I'm not very familiar with it. But it is exactly made to sit in the middle between the user and the internet server. For example besides caching internet pages [**squid** has advanced **Access Control Lists (ACL)**](https://wiki.squid-cache.org/SquidFaq/SquidAcl#Access_Controls_in_Squid) to manage sophisticated access rights. I think you should find a configuration with it that fit your needs.

Comment: can non-web browsers use proxy servers?

Comment: @Pure.Krome Yes, it is possible.

Answer (score 2):

Try nxfilter. There are tutorials on youtube.

https://sidelink.co.za/install-nxfilter-on-raspberry-pi/

You can also use adguard. It is generaly for blocking ads, but there are options in web gui to block certain services or websites for some selected clients.

Answer (score 2):

PiHole (https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole/

) could be an alternative with the parental filter addon (https://digimoot.wordpress.com/2020/07/13/pihole-use-as-a-parental-filter/).

This will also give you less ads when surfing.